# Как вычесть массив из массива?

Tags: java, android, массивы

Есть 2 массива int[], содержащие элементы Drawable.

```
int[] m1 = new int[]{R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3}
int[] m2 = new int[]{R.drawable.img1, }
```

Необходимо найти разницу, те сравнить 2 массива и оставить только неповторяющиеся элементы.

Порядок не важен. Дублирование значений в массивах исключено. Изначально известно что М1 содержит 50 элементов М2, их только нужно оттуда убрать.

Долго не было ответа, решил вот так:
Спасибо за помощь.

```
private int[] delArray(int[] a, int[] b) {
    List<Integer> list_A = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int index = 0; index < a.length; index++) {
        list_A.add(a[index]);
    }
    List<Integer> list_B = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int index = 0; index < b.length; index++) {
        list_B.add(b[index]);
    }

    list_A.removeAll(list_B);

    int[] ret = new int[list_A.size()];
    for(int i = 0;i < ret.length;i++)
        ret[i] = list_A.get(i);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Нужно больше деталей. Важен ли порядок, возможно ли дублирование значений в исходных массивах. В самом простом случае вам поможет [`Set.removeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)), но он не сохраняет порядок и не допускает дублирования элементов

Comment: @soon обновил описание.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
final int[] a1 = {12, 14, 15, 62, 12, 23};
final int[] a2 = {1, 12, 32, 23, 22};
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{ for (int a : a1) add(a); }};
List<Integer> intList_2 = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{ for (int a : a2) add(a); }};
intList.removeAll(intList_2);

for (int a : intList) System.out.println(a);
```

Итог: 14, 15, 62

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, ваш вариант в итоге выводит List<Integer>, не хватает обратного преобразования.

Answer (score 3):

В случае, если порядок элементов неважен и входные массивы не содержат дублирующихся эллементов, то самый простой путь - создать `Set` из массива и удалить из него все элементы, содержащиеся во втором массиве:

Проблема лишь в том, как нормально создать `Set` из массива. Стандартный конструктор `HashSet` принимает `Collection<T>`, поэтому необходимо преобразовать `int[]` в список (к примеру). Если есть поддержка Google Guava, то можно воспользоваться стандартным методом [`Ints.asLists`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList(int...)). Его сложность в документации не указана, но если заглянуть в реализацию, то можно увидеть, что это О(1):

```
int[] m1 = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] m2 = new int[]{0, 4, 2, 8};

Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>(Ints.asList(m1));
s.removeAll(Ints.asList(m2));
s.forEach(System.out::println);
```

В противном случае можно создать свой метод для создания множества из целочисленного массива:

```
public static Set<Integer> asSet(int[] arr) {
    Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();
    for (int x : arr) {
        s.add(x);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Ну а если есть поддержка Java 8 (полагаю, в рамках Android это пока неуместно, но все же), то можно воспользоваться `Stream`:

```
Set<Integer> s = IntStream.of(m1).boxed().collect(toSet());
s.removeAll(IntStream.of(m1).boxed().collect(toList()));
s.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Если элементов немного, то можно обойтись без множеств а просто проверить все элементы (осторожно: квадратичная сложность):

```
IntStream.of(m1).filter(x -> IntStream.of(m2).noneMatch(y -> x == y)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Очень ценные рекомендации, благодарю.

Comment: А не подкажите, какой магией можно преобразовать массив в set за O(1). Интересует идея алгоритма применительно к стандартным стукрутарм, можно ссылкой.

Comment: @pavel, обратите внимание, там не массив в сет, а массив в список за O(1). За O(1) массив в сет, разумеется, никак не получится.

Comment: @pavel Соль в том, что конструктор HashSet не позволяет передать напрямую `int[]`, так что приходится изворачиваться с созданием листа. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо,  я всегда думал создание списка из массива будет O(n). Такая скорость достигается тем что внутри списка будет лежать внутри массив? Т.е. редактируя массив мы меняем список?

Comment: @pavel, именно. Стандартный метод [Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)), кстати, должен давать аналогичную сложность